# Inappropriate to ask why job was cancelled?

Tags: interviewing, internship

I recently applied to an internship job posting at a start-up. I received an interview that in my opinion went very well. A few days later on the day that I was to hear back regarding my status I receive no update. After 2 emails asking for that update I am told that the position was cancelled and I will be kept in mind for future openings. Is it inappropriate to ask the company why the position was cancelled? Do I have any right to be given some sort of justification or just avoid being ghosted?

Comment: I'm surprised you seemed to be expecting a reply unconditionally. It makes it seem like you were expecting a reply even if it was negative or were 100% sure you would be hired but but never heard from them. I don't normally expect to hear a response unless I got the job.

Comment: I don't think you have any right for them to tell you anything. It's annoying, sure, but that's often how it is being an applicant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It is not inappropriate, but mostly pointless**

I wouldn't see a problem with asking as it can let you know whether you could be applying for other positions within the company or whether there is an overall hiring freeze, making any applications futile. But I would not expect a reliable answer.

Beyond learning that, what do you have to achieve other than satisfying your curiosity?

Comment: I suppose mostly curiousity, but also I might be more or less inclined to apply again in the future depending on the response

Comment: @JoshZwiebel Let's face it, they going to say something agreeable. Currently the most popular example is going to be around the prevailing economic situation we all find ourselves in.

Answer (score 11):

> Is it inappropriate to ask the company why the position was cancelled?

It's not inappropriate, but it would likely be pointless. There could be any number of reasons. Knowing the reason isn't going to change anything.

> Do I have any right to be given some sort of justification or just
> avoid being ghosted?

The company doesn't owe you anything and you, likewise, don't owe them anything. They haven't ghosted you. They've told you that the position has been cancelled. That's a perfectly acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would reply back with something like,

> Interviewer, thank you for taking the time to reply. It is disappointing to hear that the position was cancelled. I was really interested in the position and look forward to any future position you may have open. Attached is my updated resume and links to any online resume I may have. Looking forward to hearing from you in the future. Thank you.